# Godaddy SSL Certificate on Tomcat - jsse.alias_no_key_entry Error

Tags: apache-http-server, java, ssl-certificate, tomcat, godaddy

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/etc/pki/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="xxXXX"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>


SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1055)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:608)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:491)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:224)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1116)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:557)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:330)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:239)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error! In my case, the problem was due to the certificate I was using. My keystore only had a trustedCertType certificate. There should also be a private key added in it. What I did is merge my certificate and private key files into one PKCS12 file. Then I imported that p12 file into my keystore, changed the alias on my server.xml config and restarted Tomcat.

Comment: Hello, Please add implementation in your answer